# How to open a pop-up page and render a JSF Response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, servlets

I am using JSF 1.2 without any component libs for a JSF Application. Consider a case where I have a JSF rendered page and on click of a link in that page,a pop-up page should open and show some details which are from the backing bean? What are the options? since the pop up page is just a look up (read only data) , I am thinking to use javascript + Ajax + Servlet to show the data without using JSF. Are there any other options ? Thanks

Comment: Is the data to show in popup ready on main page creation, or is it to be selected (from db?) on click of the link?

Comment: The data is not on the main page.Data has to be loaded on click on the link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using JSF is also an option. Just use `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` on the `<h:commandLink>` that would open the page, and use a managed bean in a standard way, as if it was not a pop-up.